# Remove %20 from Page URL without removing space in title

Tags: url, title

On our corporate SP site, when I change the name of a Page in the SitePages folder, the title as shown top-left of the screen (beneath the breadcrumb) also changes. Is it possible to detach the two?

Reason for asking is I don't want the annoying %20 gone from the URL, but I don't want to join the two words together that make up the Title on the page.

i.e. URL = "/PageTitle.aspx"
Title on page = "Page Title"

Comment: @lan, please add some screenshots with what you already have and what you exactly need to can help you faster!

Answer (score 0):

For pages in page library you have option in edit property **Title** of the page from there we can change the title of page without changing the url pf the Page.

However for page in SitePages library /Wiki pages the option for edit property "Title" is missing.

To detach or to add the option of Title property in edit property you can
 modify the **"/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx"** and add **"SharePoint:ListItemProperty"** under **"PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"**.

[You also refer link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17557.sharepoint-2013-change-page-title-in-wiki-sites.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The page is not a wiki page but also I don't have the Title field in the Edit Properties, just the Name - I'm beginning to wonder if this is due to corporate policy perhaps :s